# Cannot run multi-line script within local-exec provisioner Packer / Terraform

Tags: json, azure-devops, terraform, packer

i am trying to create a VMSS and hoping to use Packer to bundle up my image and Terraform to create the rest of the Azure infra.

I am testing locally but endgame will be pushed to DevOps.  When i try to apply my terraform i get the following error:

```
 Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.packer,
│   on main.tf line 14, in resource "null_resource" "packer":
│   14:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command 'packer build \
│ -var client_id=[client] \
│ -var client_secret=[secret] \
│ -var install_password=CHANGEME! \
│ -var location=UKSOUTH \
│ -var resource_group=[resourcegroup] \
│ -var storage_account=[sa] \
│ -var subscription_id=[sub] \
│ -var temp_resource_group_name=rg-packerbuild-test \
│ -var tenant_id=[tenant] \
│ -var virtual_network_name=[vnet] \
│ -var virtual_network_resource_group_name=[resource group] \
│ -var virtual_network_subnet_name=hosts \
│ windows2022.pkr.json
│ ': exit status 1. Output: Error: Could not find any config file in \
│
│ A config file must be suffixed with `.pkr.hcl` or `.pkr.json`. A folder can be
│ referenced.
```

```
locals {
  ami_name = join("-", [var.name, formatdate("YYYYMMDDhhmmss", timestamp())])
}

resource "null_resource" "packer" {
  triggers = {
    ami_name = local.ami_name
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = path.module
    command     = <<-EOF
    packer build \
    -var client_id=${var.client_id} \
    -var client_secret=${var.client_secret} \
    -var install_password=${var.install_password} \
    -var location=${var.location} \
    -var resource_group=${var.resource_group} \
    -var storage_account=${var.storage_account} \
    -var subscription_id=${var.SubscriptionId} \
    -var temp_resource_group_name=${var.TempResourceGroupName} \
    -var tenant_id=${var.TenantId} \
    -var virtual_network_name=${var.VirtualNetworkName} \
    -var virtual_network_resource_group_name=${var.VirtualNetworkRG} \
    -var virtual_network_subnet_name=${var.VirtualNetworkSubnet} \
    windows2022.pkr.json 
EOF
  }
}
```

The file is there and i have added a `dir` command before the `packer build` command and it lists out the correct file path.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding the `interpreter` commands and changing the `\`.

Hope this helps someone.

```
 provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = path.module
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
    command     = <<-EOT
    packer build `
    -force `
    -var client_id=${var.client_id} `
    -var client_secret=${var.client_secret} `
    -var install_password=${var.install_password} `
    -var location=${var.location} `
    -var resource_group=${var.resource_group} `
    -var storage_account=${var.storage_account} `
    -var subscription_id=${var.SubscriptionId} `
    -var temp_resource_group_name=${var.TempResourceGroupName} `
    -var tenant_id=${var.TenantId} `
    -var virtual_network_name=${var.VirtualNetworkName} `
    -var virtual_network_resource_group_name=${var.VirtualNetworkRG} `
    -var virtual_network_subnet_name=${var.VirtualNetworkSubnet} `
    windows2022.json 
    EOT
  }
}
```